# CSS selector after class

Tags: html, css

I am a total beginner in css, and I came across the following code which I don't understand.

```
.single-product h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.single-product h2 a {
    color: #222;
}
.single-product p {
    color: #1abc9c;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

What is the difference between, say h2.single-product {}, compared to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

- `h2.single-product` matches h2 elements with the class single-product
- `.single-product h2` matches h2 elements that are within any element with the class single-product

See bellow the examples applicable for each case.

```html
    <!-- first declaration -->
    <h2 class="single-product">Testberichte</h2>

    <!-- second declaration -->     
    <div class="single-product">
        <h2>hi</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? As I am a total beginner I can't see the difference

Comment: yes i can. i will provide one example of each case.

Answer (score 0):

'h2.single-product' will apply the following style to *a h2 element that has the class single-product*.

'.single-product h2' will apply the style to *a h2 element that is a child node of an element that has the class single-product*.

The whitespace character in CSS is a selector by itself, called "child node" selector; just like the "." character is called the "class" selector.

Comment: Your answer is helpful because you provided the keyword "child node". I will research on that.

Comment: You can find a list of css selectors with more explanation here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

For

```
h2.single-product {}
```

**single-product** class property shows its effect when it is in any **h2** tag.

For

```
.single-product h2
```

Property of **h2** tag only works when it is in **single-product** class